# Build error when packaging multiple nuget targets

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

I'm attempting to make a Nuget package for multiple framework targets (.netstandard20 and net46). I am able to build the solution and the outputs appear on disk as expected, but whenever I try to package them (Visual Studio 2019 or msbuild directly), I'm getting the following error:

`error MSB4057: The target "_GetBuildOutputFilesWithTfm" does not exist in the project.`

I'm not using a .nuspec file and the developer packages of my target frameworks are installed correctly.

Here's my .csproj (with nuget metadata excluded for brevity) - it's pretty basic:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net46</TargetFrameworks>
    <ReleaseVersion>1.0</ReleaseVersion>
    <PackageVersion>1.0</PackageVersion>

    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType></DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net46'">
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack" Version="5.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Build.Packaging" Version="0.2.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Does anyone have any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you target both?  Unless I'm mistaken, .NET Framework 4.6.1 supports .NET Standard 2.0.  Seems like you could just drop 4.6 as a target?

Comment: Try removing the package reference to `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack`. That's only needed for non-SDK style projects. `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` brings it in automatically, even when targeting the .NET Framework TFMs.

Comment: @Zer0 - Sure. When adding the nuget package to a .net 4.7 (desktop) project, the package added a reference to almost every .net core "System.x" namespace for some reason which caused all sorts of build errors. I tried adding "RestoreProjectStyle" as "PackageReference" in the csproj, but to no avail. After spending far too much time trying to get the full framework respecting .netstandard20 (as it should), I figured a different build target would work just as well (ironically). Any thoughts on this behaviour?

Comment: That's very bizarre sounding to me.  AFAIK, .NET Standard is a subset of .NET Core.  I wonder if I can reproduce this.

Comment: @zivkan - I tried removing `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack` and `NuGet.Build.Packaging` and that seemed to work. Better yet, by retargeting my csproj to just netstandard2.0 - I'm able to reference this in .net 4.7.x as well as .net core using the same package now (my original goal). Thank you!

Comment: @Zer0 It is - I removed the packages `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack` and `NuGet.Build.Packaging` and am now able to target both frameworks (.net 4.7.x and .net core) from the single package using `netstandard20` now (as we'd expect) :-)  Thank you for taking the time to look!

Comment: Glad it's solved.  Please accept an answer so this is closed out and useful to others with this problem.  I'll briefly make an answer for this, or feel free to write and accept your own answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing references to `NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack` and `NuGet.Build.Packaging` allows targeting only .NET Standard 2.0 and getting the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you and @zivkan for your help :-)